# Don't let a user type the period character in an HTML5 input type number

Tags: html

So right now the user is able to insert a decimal value in the number field of the HTML5 input type="number". I want to prevent that, so if a user types "5.1" it will insert "51" in the textbox.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You have a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definite answer is this:

```
function preventDot(e) {
            var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;

            if (key == 46) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
```

And bind it on keydown

Comment: [keypress is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event)

Comment: @RuanMendes thanks. It wasn't 7 years ago when I wrote this answer. I changed it to keydown now

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to find the characters that make the value a decimal value, and then delete them so that the value internally becomes an integer:

```
/[\.,]/
```

Comment: There's a simple reason for this: In my home country the period doesn't mean "decimal place" but "thousands place". Therefore, a user will type 7.900 and it will parse it as 7, which would be wrong