# How to allow only integers in input control

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angular

Is there an easy way to allow users to enter only integers positive and negative. I can do it with few lines of JavaScript or jQuery but hope there is an easy way like regex. But I could not found what I need.
I need to be able to enter these characters:
-0123456789

```
<input id="myID" type="number">
```

I don't need dot/coma/exp char. Only -0123456789, i.e. positive and negative integers

Comment: Isn't that what `type="number"` does? I don't get the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Comment: Didn't you do any research before asking this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233040/dont-let-a-user-type-the-period-character-in-an-html5-input-type-number

Comment: As I said I don't want to use jQuery.. And HTML code above allows to enter dot and 'e' that I don't want to

Comment: @JohnGlabb The regex on the link I posted will work if you modify it to `/[\.,]/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when you use `type="number"`, it'll not do what you want, I have a solution for you using `type="text"`

```html
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\-/g, '$1');" >
```

Comment: this example works fine but I thought there is better approach to use pure regex. I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2):

```html
<input id='number' type='number' pattern="[0-9\-]+">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `pattern` attribute where you can specify your own regex for the input. For more info, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp). It is the closest thing you can get if you do not want to write any javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern` attribute with `RegExp` `[0-9-]|[^e]` and `required` attribute within a `<form>` element

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" pattern="[0-9-]|[^e]" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @JohnGlabb _"it doesn't work.. It allows enter letters."_ At which browser? The JavaScript artifact E-notation `e` can be entered, though not submitted

Comment: FireFox doesn't work at all.. In Chrome it allows enter dot and 'e'

Comment: @JohnGlabb _"In Chrome it allows enter dot and 'e' "_ At Chromium 61 E-notation `e` can be entered, but the `<form>` will not be submitted when `e` or `.` is within the value. At which version of Chrome did you try stacksnippets? _"FireFox doesn't work at all.."_ Just tried at Firefox 57, with same results; that is, the `<form>` is not submitted if either `e` or `.` is within `value` of `<input>` as the value will be invalid when matched against the `RegExp` at `pattern` attribute. Not certain what you mean by "doesn't work at all"?

Comment: @JohnGlabb Does the `<form>` submit when either or both `e` and `.` are included at value of `<input>` at the browsers you tried code?

Comment: I don't want to allow dot and 'e' at all. FF - 56.0.1, Chrome - 61.0.3163.100. Seems Being Sunny has a solution.. See below

Comment: @JohnGlabb Do you mean that you are trying to prevent user from typing `e` and `.` at all?  What is the purpose of this sentence at Question _"I can do it with few lines of JavaScript or jQuery but hope there is an easy way like regex."_ ? You already had a solution "with few lines of JavaScript " that you had written before posting Question, yes? What exactly is the issue with the code that you had previously written?

Comment: well, I'm looking for e.g. pure regex solution instead of this:

<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\-/g, '$1');" >

Comment: @JohnGlabb What do you mean by "pure regex solution"? Where should `RegExp` be used?

Comment: Ok.. I mean pure HTML to use e.g. type, pattern, e.t.c.. or any other attributes. Why it's so complicated to implement so I need to use JavaScript. I thought there is an easy solution, like a control property

Comment: @JohnGlabb _"I mean pure HTML to use e.g. type, pattern, e.t.c.. or any other attributes."_ Why do you expect HTML alone to be able to implement "allow users to enter only integers positive and negative"?